# Access_token for graph api calls in JavaScript

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token

I am trying to pull in and display the wall posts and comments from a public Facebook page on my client's webpage using JavaScript. I know I need an access_token, but the problem is it expires every so often. It seems I would need to dynamically get the access_token to avoid that issue. Does anyone know of a way to do this client-side?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

If the page is really public, you don't need an access token at all.  For instance,

```
http://graph.facebook.com/19292868552
{
   "id": "19292868552",
   "name": "Facebook Platform",
   "picture": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-ash2/276791_19292868552_1958181823_s.jpg",
   "link": "http://www.facebook.com/platform",
   "likes": 3922010,
   "category": "Product/service",
   "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
   "username": "platform",
   "founded": "2007",
   "company_overview": "Facebook Platform enables anyone to build social apps on Facebook and the web.",
   "mission": "To make the web more open and social.",
   "about": "We're building the social web. Get the latest here: developers.facebook.com ",
   "talking_about_count": 74536
}
```

Longer answer, if you are using a particular user's access token to perform actions on their behalf, you might consider asking for "offline access" so that the token won't expire.  See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/ for more information about how to ask for this permission.

Comment: Offline access has been deprecated though because Facebook likes to be a pain in the ass and break things.

Comment: that is going to break things for sure.